# Run PHP in Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I can't get run PHP in Google Cloud Storage. Every time it downloads the page instead of run.

I saw in Documentation Troubleshooting, if page get's downloadet change Meta Type to text/HTML

Instead of run PHP it looks like, if you see a PHP site in XAMPP with inactivate server.

Do I have to install client libaries on Google Cloud to get PHP run, or Appache?

What can I do to get PHP run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not provide compute services. Cloud Storage only supports static web sites.

PHP requires compute services provided by services such as App Engine, Compute Engine, etc. Also, you cannot install Apache on Cloud Storage. Typically PHP is "hosted" by a web server such as Apache or Nginx.

Google offers a number of services to host a website. You can continue to store your static assets (images, JavaScript, css, etc.) on Cloud Storage.

[Google Cloud web hosting services](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting)